# Горизонтальный скроллинг до активного элемента

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Есть блок с горизонтально расположенными элементами. Блок длинный. Используется горизонтальный скролл. Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на новый элемент, происходил скроллинг к нему? Есть [набросок на jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/su9grz30/2/), но так сроллинг происходит как-то коряво. Иногда бывает недоскролливает, если кликать на дальние элементы. Вот код:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="testBox">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item act"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="diag">Расстояние до элемента: <span>0</span>px</div>
```

CSS

```
.diag {
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
.container {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.testBox {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
}
.testBox .inner {
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.testBox .inner .item {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: #f8b068;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.testBox .inner .act {
  background-color: #6ce890;
}
.testBox .inner .item:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

JS (jQuery)

```
$('.testBox .inner .item').click(function() {
        $('.testBox .inner .item').removeClass('act');
    $(this).addClass('act');
    let elemBase = $('.testBox .inner').offset().left,
        elemActive = $('.testBox .inner .act').offset().left;
    elemActive = elemActive - elemBase;
    $('.testBox .inner').animate({
        scrollLeft: elemActive
    }, 100);
    $('.diag span').text(elemActive);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне стало это интересно и я решил с нуля написать решение вашего вопроса, он проще и эффективнее - [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/inmake/kh12xLfq/)

```
var containerOuterWidth = $('.container').outerWidth(); // узнаем ширину контейнера (width + padding)

// обработчик клика по элементу
$(".item").click(function() {
  var itemOuterWidth = $(this).outerWidth(); // узнаем ширину текущего элемента (width + padding)
  var itemOffsetLeft = $(this).offset().left; // узнаем значение отступа слева в контейнере у текущего элемента
  var containerScrollLeft = $(".container").scrollLeft(); // узнаем текущее значение скролла

  var positionCetner = (containerOuterWidth / 2 - itemOuterWidth / 2); // рассчитываем позицию центра

  var scrollLeftUpd = containerScrollLeft + itemOffsetLeft - positionCetner; // рассчитываем положение скролла относительно разницы отступа элемента и центра контейнера

  // анимируем
  $('.container').animate({
    scrollLeft: scrollLeftUpd
  }, 400);
});
```

Элемент перемещается ровно в центр!
Вы можете использовать разную ширину вашего контейнера и ваших элементов и это будет работать корректно.
Также вы можете изменять свойства margin и padding, это не скажется на результате.

Обратите внимание, я использовал **jQuery** и CSS библиотеку **Normalize**.

Comment: Да, классно получилось! Сейчас посмотрю, как Вы это сделали. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Разделите Ваши `item` на блоки, и id блока добавьте в качестве `data` атрибута, тем самым образуя что-то типо пейджинга. Зная ширину `item + margin` можно умножить на `index`элемента, тем самым узнаете на каком расстоянии в пикселях расположен элемент от левого края. Если `item` формируются перебором `for`, то просто подставляйте `index` в `data-id`. Решение ниже с Вашим кодом:

```js
$('.testBox .inner .item').click(function(e) {
  $('.testBox .inner .item').removeClass('act');
    $(this).addClass('act');
    let elemBase = $('.testBox .inner').offset().left,
        elemActive = $('.testBox .inner .act').offset().left;
        elemActive = (e.target.offsetWidth + 5) * parseInt(e.target.dataset.id); // 5 это margin-right
    $('.testBox .inner').animate({
        scrollLeft: elemActive
    }, 100);
    $('.diag span').text(elemActive);
});
```

```css
.diag {
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
.container {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.testBox {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
}
.testBox .inner {
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.testBox .inner .item {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: #f8b068;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.testBox .inner .act {
  background-color: #6ce890;
}
.testBox .inner .item:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="testBox">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="item" data-id="0"></div>
      <div class="item" data-id="1"></div>
      <div class="item act" data-id="2"></div>
      <div class="item" data-id="3"></div>
      <div class="item" data-id="4"></div>
      <div class="item" data-id="5"></div>
      <div class="item" data-id="6"></div>
      <div class="item" data-id="7"></div>
      <div class="item" data-id="8"></div>
      <div class="item" data-id="9"></div>
      <div class="item" data-id="10"></div>
      <div class="item" data-id="11"></div>
      <div class="item" data-id="12"></div>
      <div class="item" data-id="13"></div>
      <div class="item" data-id="14"></div>
      <div class="item" data-id="15"></div>
      <div class="item" data-id="16"></div>
      <div class="item" data-id="17"></div>
      <div class="item" data-id="18"></div>
      <div class="item" data-id="19"></div>
      <div class="item" data-id="20"></div>
      <div class="item" data-id="21"></div>
      <div class="item" data-id="22"></div>
      <div class="item" data-id="23"></div>
      <div class="item" data-id="24"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="diag">Расстояние до элемента: <span>0</span>px</div>
```

Comment: Да... Точно... Спасибо!

Comment: @LexXy пожалуйста!